# Golang exec command chmod returning error

Tags: shell, go, exec, wildcard

Familiarizing myself with Golang here and i am trying to execute shell commands, i need to chmod for any .pem file so i decided to use the wildcard *

```
func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command( "chmod", "400", "*.pem" )

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stdout

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println( "Error:", err )
    }
```

I keep get this error while executing:

```
chmod: cannot access '*.pem': No such file or directory
Error: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells.

So here, `*` will not be expanded. As a workaround, you should use next to make it work:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "chmod 400 *.pem" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to change a file permission using os package

```
filepath.WalkDir(".", func(filePath string, f fs.DirEntry, e error) error {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    if filepath.Ext(f.Name()) == ".pem" {
        err := os.Chmod(filePath, 0400)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Successfully changed file permission, file: %s", filePath))
    }
    return nil
})
```

Complete code can be found at https://play.golang.org/p/x_3WsYg4t52

Comment: Didn't work for me, tho it ran without errors, this could have been the best approach

Comment: Did you see the log in the console "Successfully changed file permission, file:"?

Comment: Please replace "." with appropriate path if pem file location is different from execution dir.